# Windows DNS and Domain Controller - difference between physical and remote log-on

Tags: windows, networking, dns, remote-desktop, domain

Windows Domain environment.

Windows XP machine.

I tried logging on to a domain-joined computer at the computer itself and I got an error saying it could not find domain controller.
I then jumped on my work computer and pinged both IP and hostname and the pings worked. I then remoted in via Windows Remote Desktop Connection was able to connect via hostname and IP.

Once inside the machine, I ran ipconfig flushdns and registerdns and logged off. I was then able to log on physically in front of the machine.

I understand that server DNS records were good so I could ping hostname and remote in but I couldn't log in physically but the computer's local DNS was corrupt and could not find domain controller.

My question is, how was I able to remote in? Isn't the computer in question looking for a domain controller the same way or is there a different process that takes place when remote-ing in versus logging on at phyiscal log on console.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Unfortunately, your question is considered off-topic here at SuperUser because it is speculation. There can be too many things that are the reason, and there is no way to know which one of the possible many answers is the correct one, because the problem no longer exists.. For example, it is possible there was a network malfunction at the exact time of trying to log into the computer at the time. It could have been that the server was rebooting. It could be that the DNS cache referred to an old ip address, amongst others.

Comment: LPChip raises a very good point.  We are always glad to help, but there are too many factors in the equation.  Last but certainly not least, why is the domain still utilizing Windows XP machines?  Without any additional support or security patches from Microsoft, using WinXP workstations is a risky proposition.